# Filtering collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say we have a collection of Person objects

```
class Person 
{
     public string PersonName {get;set;}
     public string PersonAddress {get;set;}    
}
```

And somewhere in the code defined collection

```
List<Person> pesonsList = new List<Person>();
```

We need to have a filter that need to filter the collection and return the result to the end user. Let's say we have a collection of Filter type objects

```
class Filter 
{
    public string FieldName {get;set;}
    public string FilterString {get;set;}
}
```

And somewhere in the code we have

```
List<Filter> userFilters = new List<Filter>();
```

So we need to filter the content of the personsList collection by filters defined in the userFilters collection. Where the **Filter.FieldName == "PersonName" || Filter.FieldName == "PersonAddress"**. How can I do that with LINQ in a cool way ? The solutions like switch/case, or 
may be, I thought, extension method on personsList that determines from the FiledName the property of the Person to look into, are known. Something else ? Something tricky:)
Thank you.

Comment: Is this using in-memory LINQ or LinqToSql?

Comment: This is in-memory LINQ. I need to query a set of objects defined in collection with filters defined in other collection. There is  no any DB interaction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build a lambda expression to create a proper predicate using the `Expression` class.

```
public static Expression<Func<TInput, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TInput>(
                                                   IEnumerable<Filter> filters)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TInput), "");
    Expression lambdaBody = null;
    if (filters != null)
    {
        foreach (Filter filter in filters)
        {
            Expression compareExpression = Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(param, filter.FieldName),
                    Expression.Constant(filter.FilterString));
            if (lambdaBody == null)
                lambdaBody = compareExpression;
            else
                lambdaBody = Expression.Or(lambdaBody, compareExpression);
        }
    }
    if (lambdaBody == null)
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, bool>>(Expression.Constant(false));
    else
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, bool>>(lambdaBody, param);
}
```

With this helper method, you can create an extension method on any `IQueryable<T>` class, so this should work for every LINQ backend:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
                                          IEnumerable<Filter> filters)
{
    return Queryable.Where(source, CreateFilterExpression<T>(filters));
}
```

...which you can call like this:

```
var query = context.Persons.Where(userFilters);
```

If you want to support `IEnumerable<T>` collections as well, you'll need to use this extra extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                           IEnumerable<Filter> filters)
{
    return Enumerable.Where(source, CreateFilterExpression<T>(filters).Compile());
}
```

Note that this only works for string properties. If you want to filter on fields, you'll need to change `Expression.Property` into `Expression.Field` (or `MakeMemberAccess`), and if you need to support other types than string properties, you'll have to provide more type information to the `Expression.Constant` part of the `CreateFilterExpression` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via reflection:

```
IQueryable<Person> filteredPersons = personsList.AsQueryable();
Type personType = typeof(Person);
foreach(Filter filter in userFilters) {
    filteredPersons = filteredPersons.Where(p => (string)personType.InvokeMember(filter.FieldName, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, p, null) == filter.FilterString);
}
```

(not compiled, but this should be along the right track)

Comment: Cool! I don't know, honestly, if I will apply this technique on my real code, by the way it's very nice. I love generic stuff, even if it's not so good for performance reasons. Unfortunately I'm not able to vote for your answer (my reputation is under 15), but answer is definitely great.

Comment: Note that this won't work on most LINQ backends; I very much doubt LINK to SQL will be able to translate reflection calls into SQL.

Comment: Yes, I agree. By the way, in my  case, I do not need any DB interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do

```
personList.Where(x => x.PersonName == "YourNameHere").ToList() ?
```

Comment: the filter consists of FieldName property, so I don't know if the user wants to filter against PersonName or PersonAddress, or may be some other possible properties of Person class.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to the `Filter` class to check if the filter is satisfied:

```
class Filter 
{
    public string FieldName {get;set;}
    public string FilterString {get;set;}

    public bool IsSatisfied(object o)
    { return o.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName).GetValue(o, null) as string == FilterString;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var filtered_list = personsList.Where(p => userFilters.Any(f => f.IsSatisfied(p)));
```