# C# search query with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make a suitable linq query to accomodate my search functionality.

I have a table with the following columns: 'firstname' | 'lastname' | 'description'.
with the following data: 'Peter' | 'Mulder' | 'This is a little description.'

My 'search' keyword could be something like: "peter" or "a little description".

Now if I use the following linq expression in lambda:

```
mycontext.persons
    .Where(t => 
        search.Contains(t.Firstname) || 
        search.Contains(t.Lastname) || 
        search.Contains(t.Description).Select(p => p)
    .ToList();
```

Now I get my result, when I use 'peter', but if I use 'pete' or 'a little description' I get no results.
How can I make my linq expression, so it can search through the column data for matches?

Comment: you can have a look here: [Filtering collection with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324774/filtering-collection-with-linq)

Comment: `search.Contains(t.Firstname)` or `t.Firstname.Contains(search)`?

Comment: What you are doing is  `"'pete' or 'a little description'".Contains("peter")` for your first test in the Linq, and that will always return false.

Comment: Oh my God. You guys are so right. I had done it backwards and kept staring at the wrong places.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you just have it backwards:

```
mycontext.persons
    .Where(t => 
        t.Firstname.Contains(search) || 
        t.Lastname.Contains(search) || 
        t.Description.Contains(search))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: That won't work. His search string == `"'pete' or 'a little description'"`.

Comment: @CodeNaked: Says who? He said his search string might be "pete", or it might be "a little description".

Comment: Just wondering is there a missing parenthesis before .Select?

Comment: My 'search' keyword could be something like: `"peter" or "a little description"`....but if I use `'pete' or 'a little description'`.

Comment: Solution looks good. But is the .Select(p => p) even needed? There is a missing end parenthesis after t.Description.Contains(search)

Comment: @DylanVester you're right. I guess I was just focusing on the fact that the OP has the search logic backwards.

Comment: Oh my God. You guys are so right. I had done it backwards and kept staring at the wrong places.

Comment: this method works fine i was looking for something like this in my case(entity framework)

Answer (score 4):

One possible (but probably not the most optimized solution) would be to append all of your fields together and do a `Contains` on the search term., e.g.

```
var result = persons.Where(q => (q.Description + " " q.FirstName + " " q.LastName)
                    .ToLower()
                    .Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: you might want to add a delimiter of some sort, otherwise a search like "tionpete" will match incorrectly.

Comment: Oh my God. You guys are so right. I had done backwards and kept staring at wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

try This Code.

```
private void SearchData()
{
    Model1Container model = new Model1Container();
    try
    {
        var query = model.Scholars.AsQueryable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtSearch.Text))
        {
            //  query = query.Where(x=>x.ScholarName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text));
            query = (from Schl in model.Scholars
                where Schl.ScholarName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text) ||
                      Schl.PhoneRes.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text) ||
                      Schl.PhoneOff.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text) ||
                      Schl.Mobile.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text) ||
                      Schl.Email.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text)
                orderby Schl.ScholarName
                select Schl);
        }
        this.dgvScholarList.DataSource = query.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```